# rails engines and assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

I have a rails engine that has a widget in it. I'm rendering the widget using a `layout: false` property in render and to style the widget, I'm recycling CSS on my main app.

Now here's the tricky part, I only needed 3 stylesheets for my widget and 2 of them are in my main app, those are bootstrap.css and _ss_font.css. On development, it works fine but when I push it to production, I'm having an error on bootstrap.css, it seems that it's dependent on another file on my vendor assets. How do I include those assets?

Note: If I use `=stylesheet_link_tag "application"` my problem is partially resolved but I have to handle conflicting class names and it will include all assets on my application. I just want to load the necessary stylesheets to style my widget in the engine.

**EDIT 1**

As suggested I'm including a more descriptive explanation on this:

So this is the error I'm having.

> ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable:
>   ss-variables. Load path:
>   /data/serviceseeking_au_staging/releases/20140604114806   (in
>   /data/serviceseeking_au_staging/releases/20140604114806/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss)):
>
> ```
> 2: !!! 5
> 3: %html
> 4:   %head
> 5:     = stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap", "_ss_font", "feedback/reviews-widget" 
> 6: 
> 7:   %body
> 8:     .reviews-container   
> lib/action_logger.rb:31:in `call'
> ```

This view is inside the engine. As you can see, this is my ideal goal, to only include 3 stylesheets. There's not much to see on the `reviews-widget`, it's just sass without any external file dependency so I will not show it. So looking at the error message, where is this "ss-variable"? Well, let me take you guys on a field trip first before we arrive there.

I first traced where `bootstrap.scss` is and found it sitting on the main app under the `vendor/assets/stylesheets` folder. It's contents are as follows:

```
 @import "bootstrap/variables";
 @import "bootstrap/mixins";

 @import "bootstrap/scaffolding";

 @import "bootstrap/grid"; 
 @import "bootstrap/layouts";

 etcetera...
```

So by tracing boostrap.scss and opening it, I saw that it's importing a partial named _variables.scss, so on with the tour and here's `_variable.scss`

```
@import "ss-variables";

// Grays
// -------------------------
$black:                 #000 !default;
$grayDarker:            #222 !default;
```

(**Note**: I saw another boostrap.scss inside the `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap` where _variables.ss is located) Aha! There's that little freak, "ss-variable"!! We're getting close on this wild partial chase. So I searched where `ss-variables.scss` is and found it on my `lib/assets/stylesheets/` in the main app and it contains more scss variables.

So tracing them, I formulated this hypothesis that when trying to include `bootstrap` using stylesheet_link_tag on my engine, the engine doesn't see the dependent files that lies on the main app.

Bonus: I have a remarkable feeling that after this, the `_ss_font` css will be next. But that's for another story. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, your problem *might* be caused by the [`asset_fingerprinting`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) feature of the asset pipeline - basically appends all the `production` assets with an MD5 hash

--

**Asset Fingerprinting**

Essentially, if you're using the likes of `Heroku` (which requires your assets to be precompiled for them to be served), you will basically get a series of files in your `public/assets` folder like this:

```
|-public
|--assets
|---images
|---stylesheets
|---javascripts
```

The files contained in this folder, when precompiled, all have the `fingerprinted` filename. This means if you wanted to call one of these, you will need to use one of the `ERB` / `SCSS` preprocessors to access them:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
.style {
   background: asset_url("background.png");
}
```

This will reference the file, regardless of whether it's been precompiled (& `fingerprinted`) or not. Although not exactly your issue, it *is* an important factor in what you're asking

--

**Fix**

I would suggest your issue is likely that you're referencing "static" CSS files, which really need to be dynamically referenced.

> How do I include those assets?

You'll be best using [`@import`](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5) like this:

```
#gem/app/assets/gem/widget.css.scss
@import "bootstrap.css" /* will probably need a relative path for this */
@import "other.css" /* again, will need a relative path */
```

Comment: If you give us an example of your CSS, it will be a much greater help

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the reply. I have added more description on my bugs. Hope it helps and Thanks again for your time.